# Postgres DELETE/UPDATE with Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, postgresql, python-multiprocessing, psycopg2

I'm curious as to the behavior of Postgres in this instance.

Using Python multiprocessing, I can SELECT and INSERT in batches.

The SELECT runs first independently of the INSERT which is done a separate group of processes after the SELECT have all been finished.

This works perfectly fine.  My question is why doesn't this approach work with DELETE or UPDATE?

When trying to DELETE or UPDATE with this pattern it seemingly just hangs on the second step.  From what I understand the locks are at the row level rather than the table.  What could explain this behavior?  It happens with both single row DELETEs and DELETEs using the IN operator.

For example:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE ID = ?
```

or

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE ID IN (?, ?)
```

I describe this happening with DELETE but as I mentioned the same occurs with UPDATE.  For the multiprocessing part of the code, it's just a standard way of using either `Pool` or `Process` with the SQL statements divided between `multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2` processes.

Comment: This is going to need more information added to question 1) The SELECT query 2) The Python code being run. On a general level an INSERT is new data, whereas UPDATE and DELETE are working on existing data. I'm guessing there is some lock being held on that existing data that is hanging the process. Without the information requested a guess is about the best that can be done.

Comment: I think you're right that, if the deletes/updates are being made to different rows, you would not generally expect the locks acquired by those transactions to conflict. However, it feels like you are running into more restrictive locking behaviour for some reason. Can I suggest you open a `psql` session and examine `SELECT * FROM pg_locks;` while your queries are running? You may be able to confirm that there are conflicting locks.

Comment: Aside - under the hood, Postgres runs `UPDATE` as a quasi `DELETE` + `INSERT` but not [exactly analogous](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/278476). See docs on special nature of [delete and update](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-SPACE-RECOVERY).

Comment: What is python-multiprocessing? Why do you think you need it? Does it imply multiple transactions to the database. Multiple connections? If so: would you want these?

Comment: @wildplasser I was assuming it's just the multiprocesing module.  Using it for SELECTs works great.  Even INSERTs seem to work, just not DELETEs or UPDATEs.